# Extra Padding under image inside div?

Tags: html, css

For some reason, it seems like there is extra padding on the bottom of my div that holds an image inside it.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KSs7V/

Any idea on how that got there/how to fix it?

CSS:

```
.artist-box {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.artist-pic {
    height: 245px;
    margin: 0;
    /*box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;*/
}
#artist-wrap {
    max-width: 1800px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.indArtistBox {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just add `vertical-align:top` or `display:block` to your image rules:

```
.artist-pic {
    height: 245px;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align:top;
    /*box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;*/
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KSs7V/2/)**

An alternate option is to add `font-size:0` on the image container div:

```
.indArtistBox {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KSs7V/3/)**

The gap is due to the space reserved for descender elements (e.g. 'j', 'g', 'y') as images are inline elements.